# How can I conditionally show a section based on if a filtered array would show items?

Tags: adobe-documentgeneration

I'm using [Document Generation](https://www.adobe.io/apis/documentcloud/dcsdk/docs.html) and have used filtering in lists like so:

```
{% repeating-section cats[weight > 5] %}
```

This will loop over a cats array and only show items where the weight property is over 5. This works fine, but I'm using it in a "section" with an intro and I want to hide the entire section if that particular array is empty. How can I use that in a condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [JSONata](https://docs.jsonata.org/overview.html) docs, there is a `$count` operator. This can be used to count the number of items in an array, and include the filter as well. So for example:

```
{% conditional-section expr($count(cats[weight > 5]) > 0) %}
```

This can be used around the section that includes your list.